# What does Rom mean by "If that's what's written, that's what's written"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the Season 6 episode [Favor the Bold](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Favor_the_Bold_%28episode%29), Rom and Quark have the [following conversation](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708540/quotes) while Rom is in a holding cell:

> **Rom:** You've got to finish what I started. The fate of the entire Alpha
>   Quadrant rests in your hands. Billions and billions of people are
>   counting on you.
>   **Quark**: Boy, are they gonna be disappointed.
>   **Rom**: Brother... You can do this. You have to do this. You will do this!
>   **Quark**: What happens if I get caught?
>   **Rom**: Then we'll die together - side by side, heads held high, knowing we did our best.
>   **Leeta**: Oh Rom!
>   **Quark**: But I don't want to die.
>   **Rom**: If that's what's written... then that's what's written.

I've watched this episode many times, but I've never understand what Rom means by his final sentence, *If that's what's written... then that's what's written.*

What is the significance of this phrase?

Comment: He means that if that’s what’s written, then that’s what’s written.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short Answer:

He's basically telling Quark "you can't worry about what might happen, because you will die whenever it is time for you to die no matter what you do. If it is time for you to die today, then that's what is going to happen. So you may as well try to do the best you can in the mean time."

Longer answer:

Comments about "what has been written" are usually references, literally or figuratively, to prophecy. This dates back to Biblical times (and probably way earlier, though most people know it from the Bible) where it referred to the actual prophets predicting the future. In pop culture its most famous use was in *The Ten Commandments* where Ramses says "So let it be written, so let it be done."

In a typical fantasy setting, the speaker would likely be referring to an actual, written-down prophecy spoken by some mystic or wise person in ages past. That's a very common trope used to move a story forward (e.g. give the hero something to guide their actions and/or fight against it.)

When used in the way that Rom does, it's probably figurative, and is used as a general reference to fate or destiny. In this sense it is referring to some hypothetical "written word" that describes the fate of everyone in the universe, including when/how they die. (I don't *think* there are any references to the Ferengi religion having a belief in an actual "written record" like this, though many religions do have something similar.) Rom is, in essence, saying that whatever happens is what was "supposed" to happen -- if Quark dies trying to take out the anti-graviton beam, then that is just how he is destined to die.

Comment: If you think this *is* to a specific, possibly prophetic text, and idea which one it is?

Comment: @Pureferret Wherever Nog got the [Great Material Continuum](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8hcHXwqPEo) from, most likely.  If he wasn't making it up.  I don't think it's part of the Rules of Acquisition, though..

Answer (score 9):

The Alamo, 1960 (John Wayne)(Going from memory)

Linda Cristal (as Graciela Carmela Maria 'Flaca' de Lopez y Vejar) "But we may never see each other again"

John Wayne (As Col. Davy Crockett) "If that's what's written, then that's what's written."

Answer (score 4):

Rule of Acquisition #227: "If that's what's written, then that's what's written."

Source: [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Ferengi_Rules_of_Acquisition); [Star Trek Online](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Online)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Star Trek Online, but I wonder if they got that from the DS9 episode. Nog quoting one of the Rules of Acquisition in that context does make sense, though.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to refer to fate: that if they are supposed to die, then they will die, but if they are not fated to die, then they will survive.

Rom is saying that Quark shouldn't worry about dying or not, because if they are meant to get through, they will get through, and worrying won't change that.